# Hide page until after async call returns

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, geoip, maxmind

We're using the [MaxMind asynchronous geoip2 service](http://dev.maxmind.com/geoip/geoip2/javascript/) to determine the user's country. We redirect to another site based on the country code from the service call. However, we've run into an issue where the page either partially or completely loads before the redirect happens in a second or two, which shows our main U.S. site before redirecting to a country-specific site.

We'd like to prevent the page from displaying until after the asynchronous call returns its result. Here's our code:

```
<script src="//js.maxmind.com/js/apis/geoip2/v2.1/geoip2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var onSuccess = function (location) {
        var country_code = location.country.iso_code;

        if(country_code  == "UK")
        {
            <!--
            window.location = "http://www.ourcompany.co.uk"
            //-->
        }
        else if(country_code  == "GB")
        {
            <!--
            window.location = "http://www.ourcompany.co.uk"
            //-->
        }
        // more ELSE IF statements for other countries....
    };

    var onError = function (error) { };

    // Asynchronous call to the MaxMind server
    geoip2.country(onSuccess, onError);
</script>
```

Comment: I don't think that is possible, the only way of preventing page load is `window.stop()` but it cancels the load so only refresh resumes it.
These things are usually handled by entry page and then you can remember users choice in a cookie for future vistis

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what you mean that you want to prevent the page from loading, but maybe hiding the page will do it? Use css like this:

```
body {
    display: none;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, @KJ Price. I'll rephrase the question.

Comment: Ideally you'd apply this with javascript, otherwise anyone who hits the site with js disabled will see nothing, whether they were going to get redirected or not